# Should I remove the description/keywords meta tags if I want to use structured data markups (JSON-LD)?

Tags: meta-tags, structured-data, meta-description, json-ld, meta-keywords

I run a static HTML website for my small business. It is designed in Artisteer 4 and basic HTML comes from it.

Should I remove `meta name=description` and `meta name=keywords` if I want to use structured data markups (precisely JSON-LD)?

Another question My designing software provides the option to use custom meta tags; will these be conflicting with JSON-LD?

There are some Open Graph Tags in pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add structured data, do not remove any of your existing meta tags, just add the structured data in addition. Meta description for example is a very important tag, and its behavior cannot be replicated by structured data.

Custom meta tags will not conflict with JSON-LD, they can coexist. OpenGraph tags may overlap with JSON-LD in some cases (like title, description, date), but it is perfectly fine to have them in duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leaving the meta *description* as this field is still important for search engines and some other web services that are crawling your site. Don't bother with the *keywords* as this is a vestigial artifact of an older internet and is largely ignored by most bots.